# Rails - Belongs_to Model, where Model can be any model implementing the relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to implement, in Rails 3, an association

```
class ApiCredentials < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to Model

end
```

where `Model` can be any model.

Then in the `api_credentials` table, I have fields like `model_id` and `model` to track this association.

I don't assume that the convenient standard ActiveRecord queries will still work, but has anyone implemented something like this efficiently or used another method?

In the end, all I want to do is still to check if a particular model has `ApiCredentials` but I cannot know in advance whether the model will implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

> With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might have a picture model that belongs to either an employee model or a product model.
>   [...]
>   You can think of a polymorphic `belongs_to` declaration as setting up an interface that any other model can use.

This even uses your `model_id`/`model` columns but calls them `X_id` and `X_type` where **`X`** is the association name:

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      #...
      t.integer :imageable_id
      t.string  :imageable_type
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

In your case, you'd have something like this:

```
class ApiCredential < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creditable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Pancake < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :api_credentials, :as => :creditable
end

class OneCentStamp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :api_credentials, :as => :creditable
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about polymorphic and the quick response. I think that's exactly what I need. Let me do a quick look into it!

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you. The only difference I did was I associated my model such that `Pancake has_one ApiCredential`. Hopefully no gotchas there.

Comment: @daemonsy: Should work fine with `has_one`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference (see 4.2.2.1).